# Custom formula is not working in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to add strikethrough style when a checkbox is check, but unfortunately, only one cell is applying the formula. Please see my screenshot below.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the rule to all cells in the row, use column absolute addressing in the custom formula rule, like this:

```
=$D12
```

See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/).

Comment: Wow, nice. Works really well.